# How to count in weekly intervals?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: Tickets and Subscriptions

The Tickets table has an ticket_id, comment and timestamp.
The Subscriptions table has a prod_id, begin_date, and end_date

The end result of my query should be a table that counts the number of active subscriptions and a count of the number of tickets submitted during that week period.

```
Week of     Count Tickets   Count Subs  
2019-10-10  52              620
2019-10-03  60              540
2019-09-26  79              520
2019-09-19  116             510
2019-09-12  157             500
```

I currently have a query that outputs the number of tickets we have received by week since 2015:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(week, TIMESTAMPDIFF(week, '2015-01-01', Ticket.timestamp),'2015-01-01') 'Week of', COUNT(*) 'Count Tickets'
FROM ...
WHERE ...
GROUP BY TIMESTAMPADD(week, TIMESTAMPDIFF(week, '2015-01-01', Ticket.timestamp),'2015-01-01')
ORDER BY TIMESTAMPADD(week, TIMESTAMPDIFF(week, '2015-01-01', Ticket.timestamp),'2015-01-01') DESC
```

This is working correctly and a subset of what is outputted is:

```
Week of     Count Tickets
2019-10-10  52
2019-10-03  60
2019-09-26  79
2019-09-19  116
2019-09-12  157
```

The next step is to find the number of active subscriptions during each weekly time period.

If I was only checking one date I would do something like below:

```
AND '2019-10-10' BETWEEN begin_date and end_date
```

How would I be able to do this for every week?

Comment: You should rephrase your question by starting off with the raw data.  Then show the expected output, state the logic used to get from point A to point B, and include whatever you have already tried.

Comment: Looks like you want a join `SELECT .. FROM (your query) q LEFT JOIN subscriptions s ON ..` . Follow @TimBiegeleisen advice to get more assistance.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks for the suggestion, I've revised the question.

Comment: @Serg What would I be joining on?

Comment: Not sure which ON you want exactly. Do you want intersection of the week interval and subscriptions interval? Please show sample subscription data and the result needed based on the data

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend:

```
SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM subscriptions s
        WHERE s.begin_date < t.week_of + interval 7 day AND
              s.end_date >= t.week_of
       ) as num_subs
FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(week, TIMESTAMPDIFF(week, '2015-01-01', Ticket.timestamp), '2015-01-01') as week_of,
             COUNT(*) as Count_Tickets
      FROM . . .  -- rest of query here
     ) t ;
```

Note:  This counts as a sub anyone who subscribed at any time during the week.  The logic can be tweaked if you want to count them only if they are around for the entire week, or if you want them on the first day, or whatever.

Comment: This gives an error: "Unknown column 't.week_of' in 'where clause'". I also updated it to "week_of" from your code in case it's case sensitive. Why does it give that error? Does the subquery in select not have access to the columns of t?

Comment: That error should not be generated by this query, because `t` is the table alias and `week_of` is clearly the column alias being used.

Comment: Could it be the select subquery is within other subqueries (the table I’m operating on is much more complicated, I simplified it to target the problem). The query that needs the dates is deeper in so is the table alias no longer available for it? The query looks like below. Sorry i’m new to this so it may be obvious how to fix this. Really appreciate it!

Comment: `SELECT t.*,
       (SELECT SUM(subs)
 FROM (SELECT …
 FROM (SELECT COUNT(*) subs
        FROM subscriptions s
        WHERE s.begin_date < t.week_of + interval 7 day AND
              s.end_date >= t.week_of
       GROUP BY 1) A
 LEFT JOIN …
 LEFT JOIN …
 WHERE …
 GROUP BY 1, 2) B) as num_subs
FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMPADD(week, TIMESTAMPDIFF(week, '2015-01-01', Ticket.timestamp), '2015-01-01') as week_of,
             COUNT(*) as Count_Tickets
      FROM . . .  -- rest of query here
     ) t ;`